# Copy list of file names of photos, not the photos, in Photos app from iPhone

Tags: finder, photos, photos.app, image-capture

To copy a list of file names, not the files, from Mac Finder, I can select multiple files, copy and paste into a TextEdit file.  This will paste a list of the file names.

I would like to do that with the file names from Photos app from my iPhone.  Image Capture (or Photos on Mac) will show the list of photos from the Photos app on the iPhone.  But I cannot copy (Command + C) the photos.  Therefore, I cannot paste the list of the file names into a TextEdit file.  Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You might be able to get to a directory listing of the photos on your iPhone (or a backup thereof) using [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer). _Disclaimer_: I'm a satisfied user of iExplorer and have no ties, financial or otherwise, with Macroplant LLC.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks for the suggestion. From my Mac, I was able to see the list of files from Photos on my iPhone.  I can select several of them, but I cannot copy. Command+C does not copy. Right-click does not show copy.  Edit>Copy is greyed out. Are you able to copy? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Was this using iExplorer?

Comment: @IconDaemon  Yes, I installed iExplorer and used it on my Mac.  My above comment pertains to this.